# Basic property of a tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I think that this might follow from a basic properties of tensor products, but I am q bit stuck...
Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra. Let $l/k$ be a finite field ext. of $k$. Suppose 
$A \otimes_k l$ is an integral domain. Does it follow that $A \rightarrow A \otimes_k l$
defined by $a$ to $a \otimes 1$ is injective? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $V$ and $W$ are two $k$-vector spaces, and $w\in W$ is nonzero, then the map $V\to V\otimes_k W$ sending $v$ to $v\otimes w$ is always injective, because vector spaces all have a basis, and are therefore flat.

Comment: I think you mean $V\otimes_k l$ rather than $V\otimes_k W$.

Comment: Is it obvious that somehow it does not give the trivial vector space and that the basis is the empty set?

Comment: If $W=0$ then you're right to worry. Otherwise, it's fine.

Comment: @Hoot I see. Thank you! Would it be possible that you could give me a quick justification for this by any chance?

Comment: The simplest way to prove the justification in terms of bases is to use the commutativity of tensor products with direct sums and the isomorphism $k\otimes_k W\cong W$ and write $V$ as a direct sum of copies of $k$.

Comment: Okay, cleaned it up a bit.  Hopefully it's now correct as written.